# Javascript: history not loading page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, back-button, browser-history

I have a menu that loads a new html file in a div. The loading is done by a click event attached to the menu's `<a>` tags. The loading works well and I add the new load to the history by constructing a new href with a hash tag.

But when I use the back button, the URL is updated correct in the browsers address field, but the page is never loaded. If I focus the address field and press enter it loads.

This is the javascript located in the mypage.html header.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // replace menu link click
    $(".right-menu a").live('click', function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      ev.stopPropagation();
      window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
      $("#content-right").load('mypage'+window.location.hash.substring(1)+'.html');
      return false;
    });

    // If page loads, load the content area according to the hash.
    var hrtag = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if(hrtag=="")
      hrtag='about';
    $("#content-right").load('mypage'+hrtag+'.html');
    window.location.hash = hrtag;
  });
</script>
```

This is the menu

```
<ul class="right-menu">
  <li><a href="mypage.html#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="mypage.html#screens">Screens</a></li>
  <li><a href="mypage.html#license">License</a></li>
  <li><a href="mypage.html#download">Download</a></li>
  <li><a href="mypage.html#donate">Donate</a></li>
</ul>
```

If I load the page as `mypage.html`, the javascript will append the hash `#about` and load the div id `"content-right"` with `mypageabout.html`

If I click the menu, for example *download*, it will load the div id `"content-right"` with `mypagedownload.html`

In both cases, the `window.location` will be set to the *hash* version of the page, `mypage.html#about` and `mypage.html#download` to register them in the history.

If i click the menu in the following order; *license*, *about*, *screens* and then click the browser's back button, the address field will show; `mypage.html#about`, `mypage.html#license` but it will NOT load the pages!?!

The URLs are obviously in the history, but they don't load.
Any clue to what might be wrong here?

// Thanks

**EDIT - The solution**

Thanks to Andres Gallo's article I came up with this solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // Make sure the page always load #about
    LoadIDWithURL('#content-right','myPageAbout.html');

    window.addEventListener('hashchange',function() {

      if (window.location.hash != "") {
        // We have a hash, use it!
        LoadIDWithURL('#content-right','MyPage'+window.location.hash.substring(1)+'.html');
      } else {
        // We do not have a hash, force page reload!
        window.history.go(0);
      }

    });

  });

  // Load the targetID with the URL loadURL.
  function LoadIDWithURL(targetID,loadURL) {
    $(targetID).load(loadURL);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a very detailed article on this exact topic.  It explains how to build exactly what you are trying to do.

Furthermore my article also explains how you can pass parameters in your links to have javascript do special things

Here is a link to the article http://andresgallo.com/2012/06/08/ajaxifying-the-web-the-easy-way/

The best method is to attach your functionality to your hashchanges rather than to you click events. This allows any changes in history to take advantage of your javascript functionalities.

Comment: Your article did the trick. I had to add a special case when the URL didn't had a hash by calling `window.history.go(0);`

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behaviour when navigating between pages which differ only in their hash. You have two options:

1. Use the [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/hashchange) event, or an emulation of it, to detect when the user changes the hash by navigation back or forward and update the page appropriately
2. Use the HTML5 [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) API.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with [hashchange](http://benalman.com/news/2010/07/jquery-hashchange-event-v13/)

```
$(function(){
    $(window).hashchange(function(){
       // some event
    })
})
```